# Приостановить вывод в загрузочную консоль

Tags: linux, archlinux

Как приостановить вывод в консоль при загрузке системы? Текст бежит слишком быстро, не успеваю прочитать, а <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> не получается затормозить в нужном месте. Мне нужно прочитать что пишет *luks* при запуске системы, в *dmesg* это не попадает.

Comment: это же есть в логах то что пишет система при загрузке

Comment: как я понимаю это выводится до загрузки системы и в логах этого нет

Comment: /var/log/boot.log

Comment: Shift+pgUp не помогает вернуться к той строке?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87158

Answer (score 1):

Выполните команду `less -r /var/log/boot.log` - скорее всего вы найдёте нужную вам информацию. В процессе самой же загрузки - попробуйте нажать "Pause" - честно говоря совсем не уверен что поможет, но до загрузки grub'а, на стадии управления загрузкой BIOS'ом, эта клавиша работает. Может и при загрузке ОС сработает.